# zlib to compress/decompress in a file with python

Tags: python, python-3.x, zlib

using zlib, i want to be able to compresse numpy arrays and write them in a file and then be able to read them back. I did the following

```
with open(outputFile, 'wb') as zFile:
    for row in array:
        compressed = zlib.compress(row, compressionLevel)
        zFile.write(compressed)
```

```
with open(os.path.join(path, fileName), 'rb') as zFile:
    for line in zFile:
        decompressed = zlib.decompress(line)
        data.append(decompressed)
data = np.array(data)
```

The writing process works as it fills the file and if i write simpler data with `compressionLevel = 0`, it is ok. But i can't make the reading process to work. I tried to do to `zlib.compress(row.tobytes() + '\n'.encode(), compressionLevel)` so that i can have proper lines to be read, but some element in my data seems to be interpreted as `\n`, so it does not read the real lines.

I also tried to read the file doing `zFile.read(bufferSize)` in a while loop and break the loop when there is nothing more to read, but each element previously compressed have a varying size (due to varying performance regarding each row) so i can't know the buffersize in advance.

**EDIT:** regarding answers, it seems that `np.savez_compress` is better suited but for now, i am stuck with zlib as it could be used elsewhere in the project and i cannot change it by myself for now.

Comment: @snakecharmerb thanks a lot. This is way better than what i was trying. And it actually works for me. But still i encounter problems as this solution seems to be very slow when the stream is big. The file i have for testing is around 10Mo, but the real ones will likely be around 500Mo and yet it takes me around 25sec to decompress my testing file. that is part of why i was trying to read my file line by line so that i don't have to deal with the whole remaining undecompressed part each time.

Comment: Regarding decompressobj, i thought that it wasn't outputing anything unless it has the whole real line (knowing the lenght with the header) so that i could loop over 'fake' lines and feed them to compressobj. But that is not the beahvior i have as it outputs something anytime, without having the whole real line.

Comment: As far as speed is concerned, AFAICT `zlib` is just a wrapper written in C around the system zlib library - there isn't even a `zlib.py` in the stdlib.  So I'm not sure how it can be speeded up without using less compression.

Answer (score 2):

One of the best options to compress numpy arrays is using [np.savez_compressed](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savez_compressed.html#numpy.savez_compressed).
This will be nicer but will be slower. I don't think your compression code is correct

```
import numpy as np
import zlib
input_arr = np.arange(100)
dtype = input_arr.dtype
compressed_arr = zlib.compress(input_arr, 2)
decompressed_arr = np.fromstring(zlib.decompress(compressed_arr), dtype)
```

You can also use [blosc](https://blosc.org/pages/blosc-in-depth/) which has even better performace

Comment: thank ! you can look at my post as i edited it. I cannot change from zlib for now. But what do you mean my compression code is incorrect ?

Comment: I think you should use np.fromstring when reading the string  like i did in my example code

Comment: yes, you're right, it works better with np.fromstring/np.frombuffer but still, i have problemes to read the file as i cannot read fix buffer size (each row compression results in different size), and some element of the compressed row are seen as `\n` so it does not retrieve the real lines.

Answer (score 1):

Use the builtin `numpy.savez_compressed`?
From the [numpy docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savez_compressed.html):

```
>>> test_vector = np.random.rand(4)
>>> np.savez_compressed('/tmp/123', a=test_array, b=test_vector)
>>> loaded = np.load('/tmp/123.npz')
>>> print(np.array_equal(test_array, loaded['a']))
True
>>> print(np.array_equal(test_vector, loaded['b']))
True
```

Comment: didn't know, seems great, if really this is not possible doing it with zlib, i will concider this solution, but it would be great if to have a solution with zlib as it might also be used elsewhere in the project. thank !

Comment: i get it. i'm sure it's possible w/ zlib but my attitude these days is it's almost always easier to use a library and be happy that someone else has figured out all the gotcha's and corner cases for me.

Comment: you're defenetly right. The thing is that the whole project contains C++ module (usin zlib) that interact with the python modul and the files might be used by both.

Answer (score 0):

so, to sum-up, i cannot use something else than zlib for now but :

- I can totaly compress/decompress a (unique) numpy array and write/read it to/from a file doing as follow :

```
row = array[0,:]
with open(outputFile, 'wb') as zFile:
    print(row)
    compressed = zlib.compress(row, compressionLevel)
    zFile.write(compressed)
```

```
with open(os.path.join(path, fileName), 'rb') as zFile:
    decompressed = zlib.decompress(zFile.read())
    data = np.frombuffer(decompressed, dtype=np.float))
    print(data)
```

- I added `np.frombuffer` as pointed out by sagarwal (actually `np.frombuffer` is better than `np.fromstring`) and  `print(row)` and `print(data)` gives the same thing. The probleme comes when i add a for loop in the writing process to add several compressed row in the file. thus i have trouble to retrieve each full size compressed row (with a `for line in zFile: ...`) to decompress them one at a time. Indeed, some element in each compressed row are seen as `\n` and thus is does not retrieve the real lines (wich gives `zlib.error: Error -5 while decompressing data: incomplete or truncated stream`)